# Apply Access restriction to properties inside a model in loopback [Strongloop]

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have model named **employee** and it's properties are

```
"name":"",
"dob":"",
"location":""
```

some of the default roles which are in the loopback frameworks are

```
$authenticated
$everyone
```

I wanted to

1.Allow `$authenticated` Roles  on accessing the model **employee**[*READ and WRITE*].

2.Allow `$everyone` Role only to *[READ]* the model properties except **location** property *[location is only allowed to read by ROLE $authenticated]*. ,

I added the below config in the employee.json, But did't work.

```
{
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY",
      "property": "location"
    }
```

Searched a lot, Could not able find the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will code work under my scenario, But it's not perfect, It's is kind of a work around, There are Methodologies called mixins which will do those tasks i guess. As my question is not answered i am giving solution.

```
Employee.afterRemote('**', function(ctx, result, next) {
        if(ctx.result) {
            if(Array.isArray(ctx.result)) {
              ctx.result.forEach(function (result) {
                var  is_logged_in = ctx.req.accessToken;
                if(is_logged_in == null){
                    console.log('1');
                    result.unsetAttribute('location')
                }
              });
            } else {
              ctx.result.unsetAttribute('location')
            }
          }

          next();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you can do for question 1) in your `employee.json`:

```
...
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ]
…
```

Concerning question number 2) - I think this is not possible in LoopbackJS actually (not sure).

The `property` attribute is for accessing custom methods (the remoteMethods names) you would define in your `employee.js` file - not for the model's attributes.